# Images from binding not re-appearing properly with ListView scrolling

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with an ItemsSource that is a List. The viewcell binds some String properties from MyDataModel to labels as well as an ImageSource property to an Image.

The idea is they click the button, select an image from gallery, and the image in the viewcell changes to what they selected.

That all works fine, until they scroll. When the images go off screen, and you scroll back up to them then all of the images show the same image (the last one selected, or rather the first one that appears when scrolling back up).

I realize that it's unloading the image and re-loading it.. but why isn't it getting it from the correct binding source?

Comment: Well I fixed this by using a string property that holds the image's path instead of an ImageSource object. There must be some caching going on w/ ListView and the ViewCell OnAppearing event. But a plain text property seems to get loaded back properly.

Comment: You can answer your own question so that it would be useful for others as well.

Comment: I have the same issue, but the property I am binding to is already a string. I think this occurs because the native rows (eg. UITableViewCell on iOS) are being reused. Are you sure the ImageSource -> string change you made fixed the issue? Because assigning an image url to the Image.Source property means that an ImageSource value will actually be created anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understand your question correct (without code)...
But if you have a ListView bound to a List with a custom ViewCell and want to change some showed data, the following should work:
- first change the data in the list
- then reassign the ViewCell:

```
 lvXX.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(XXyourViewCellxx));
```